# When was the term "union" first used?

Tags: terminology

I found out that the **symbol** for union, ∪, was created in 1895 by Giuseppe Peano in his *Formulario Mathematico* but of course the use of **the word "union"** in mathematics was older. Do you have a source for the earliest occurrence?

Comment: I think it was August de Morgan who introduced all these things.

Comment: By the way, I just found out that Grassmann already used the symbol ∪, as cited in Umberto Bottazzini, *Va' pensiero*, footnote at page 237.

Comment: I always thought that August de Morgan wrote before Grassmann.

Comment: De Morgan possibly wrote before Grassman, but in the comment (as opposed to the post, this is why it's a comment) I talked about the **symbol** for union.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [Earliest Uses of Symbols of Set Theory and Logic](http://jeff560.tripod.com/set.html) :

> Intersection and union. The symbols $\cap$ and $\cup$ were used by Giuseppe Peano (1858-1932) for intersection and union in 1888 in [Calcolo geometrico secondo l'*Ausdehnungslehre* di H.Grassmann](https://books.google.it/books?id=5LJi3dxLzuwC) (Cajori vol. 2, page 298).

See page 2 :

> 3. Colla scrittura $A \cup B \cup C \cup \ldots$ intenderemo la minima classe che contiene le classi $A, B, C,\ldots$, ossia la classe formata dagli enti che 
>      sono o $A$ o $B$ o $C$, ecc. Il segno $\cup$ si leggerà *o*; l'operazione indicata col segno $\cup$ chiamasi in logica *disgiunzione*; noi la diremo 
>      anche *addizione logica*; le classi $A, B,\ldots$ si diranno i *termini* della 
>      *somma* $A \cup B \cup \ldots$ [With the symbol $A \cup B \cup C \cup \ldots$ we mean the least class containing the classes $A, B, C,\ldots$, i.e. the class formed by the entities that are either $A$ or $B$ or $C$, etc. The symbol $\cup$ will be read "*or*"; the operation denoted by the symbol $\cup$ is named in logic *disjunction*; we will call it also *logical sum*; the classes $A, B,\ldots$ will be called *terms* of the *sum* $A \cup B \cup \ldots$.]

---

For the *term*, we have to search : W&R's [Principia](https://books.google.it/books?id=ke9yGmFy24sC&pg=PA27) is still under Peano's influence; see page 27 : "Similarly the *logical sum* of two classes $\alpha$ and $\beta$ ..."

Some early occurrences are :

- Felix Hausdorff, [Set theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=yvVIdH16k0YC&pg=PA18) (Engl.transl (1957) of the 3rd German ed. 1937), page 18 : "If $A, B$, are two sets, then by their *sum*, or union ..." [but it is necessary to check on the earlier German editions.]
- Waclaw Sierpinski, [Algèbre des ensembles](https://books.google.it/books?id=fZFsAAAAMAAJ) (1951), page 62 : "*somme* (ou *réunion*) des ensembles".

Comment: My fault - I meant the first use of the **word** "union". I edited my question. However, since Peano wrote about "disjunction", maybe the word "union" came later...

Comment: I also suspect Hausdorff's 1914 Foundations of Set Theory or one of earlier papers. From Boole to Zermelo they were saying "sums", and there was a trend of mixing sets and classes. According to Kanamori, Hausdorff was first to treat sets purely extensionally, so union made more sense. http://math.bu.edu/people/aki/8.pdf

Comment: Early in the 1900s, we often find $A \cup B$ for union used together with $AB$ for intersection.  [I have some author's comments on this in *Classics on Fractals*.]